# Add text to end of string if data validation is invalid

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data validation in my ranges and I want a script to insert text at the end of the string if it is invalid, otherwise leave it alone. Can this be done?

**Example:**

[image]

**"CHILLS"** is a part of my data validation and follows a conditional formatting to turn blue.
**"NOT VALIDATED"** is obviously not a part of the above validation/formatting (hence the red flag) so I would like it to append to **"NOT VALIDATED (*)"**

Comment: Can you provide your current script? And, in your situation, I thought that in order to think of your 1st question, it is required to know the condition of the data validation of the cell in your Spreadsheet. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your 2nd question in your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question?

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to read if a cell is in range of validation, if not then (run script). I will provide sample spreadsheet. And attach images of desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I would like to wait for it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LEbBZwG-yvO2z8dXk9Y6d2sOd1EV7U85wIwpVnpw2Jo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample Spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question. Can I ask you about the detail of your 2nd question? And also, can I ask you about the detail of ` would like it to append to "NOT VALIDATED (*)"`?

Comment: If Invalid Data add "(*)" to text.
Also ask color of cell.
Did the spreadsheet not make sense? Tried to show desired results.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand about `If Invalid Data add "(*)" to text.` in your 1st question. I think that this can be achieved. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question. So I cannot still think of the solution. This is due to my poor understanding. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: That is okay, I cannot explain it any other way. Do not worry about 2nd questions. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when the value except for the values set with the data validation rule is put to a cell, you want to open the color picker. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for replying. After the color picker is opened, what do you want to do?

Comment: Select color of cell, or cancel.

Comment: Thank you for replying. have to apologize for my poor English skill again. About `Select color of cell`, after the cell color was selected, what do you want to do? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your 2nd question.

Comment: I am sorry, I am having trouble explaining it in better detail. I am not worried about question 2 for the moment. If you can help me get on track to question 1 I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, in your question, you want to remove your 2nd question, and your current question has only one question. When the input value is different from the values set by the data validation rule, you want to add `(*)` to the inputted value. Is my understanding correct? In this case, the value added `(*)` is independent of the data validation rule?

Comment: That is correct. I will modify my post to eliminate Question 2

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the inputted value is not included in the values of the data validation rule, you want to add `(*)` to the inputted value.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const {range} = e;
  if (range.columnStart < 2 || range.columnEnd > 3 || range.rowStart < 3 || range.rowEnd > 6) return;
  const values = range.getDataValidation().getCriteriaValues()[0].getValues().flat();
  if (!values.includes(e.value)) {
    range.setValue(e.value + "(*)");
  }
}
```

- From your sample Spreadsheet, it supposes that the dropdown list is set to the cells "B3:C6". When you want to change this range, please modify the above script.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, from your question, the script is run by the OnEdit simple trigger. So when you directly run the script at the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful about this. When you use this script, please input the value to the cells "B3:C6".

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: That works great! My one note would be, if I delete the cell value is results in "undefined(*)" anyway to allow for cell to be blank?

Comment: I amended the string to be: `if (range.columnStart < 2 || range.columnEnd > 6 || range.rowStart < 4 || range.rowEnd > 100 || range.isBlank()) return;` and that resolved my issue. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Kevin P. About `My one note would be, if I delete the cell value is results in "undefined(*)" anyway to allow for cell to be blank?`, when you modify `if (!values.includes(e.value)) {` to `if (e.value && !values.includes(e.value)) {`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: @Kevin P. Now I noticed your next replying. I think that `range.isBlank()` can be also used. Thank you.